# ddl operation trigger in oracle create or alter or drop or TRUNCATE or RENAME ON SCHEMA

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-trigger

How can I prevent some `DDL` operations such as `CREATE`, `ALTER`, `DROP`, `TRUNCATE`, `RENAME` within a schema. I tried the code below :

```
create or replace TRIGGER t2
before create or alter or drop or TRUNCATE or RENAME
ON SCHEMA
DECLARE
 oper ddl_log.operation%TYPE;
BEGIN
  IF oper = 'CREATE' THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20998, 'Attempt To CREATE cannot perform DDL operation');

  ELSIF oper = 'ALTER' THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20999, 'Attempt To ALTER A cannot perform DDL operation');

  ELSIF oper = 'DROP' THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20999, 'Attempt To DROP A cannot perform DDL operation');

  ELSIF oper = 'TRUNCATE' THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20999, 'Attempt To TRUNCATE A cannot perform DDL operation');

  ELSIF oper = 'RENAME' THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20999, 'Attempt To RENAME A cannot perform DDL operation');

  END IF;
END;
```

Comment: using trigger cannot perform ddl operation

Answer (score 0):

try something like:

```
create or replace trigger
a_ddl_trigger
AFTER DDL ON DATABASE
BEGIN
insert into myloggingtable (fields) values ();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following `DDL` trigger :

```
create or replace trigger trg_admin_ddl before ddl on schema
declare
begin
 pr_ddl_oper;
end;
```

where `pr_ddl_oper` is a stored procedure with the code :

```
create or replace procedure pr_ddl_oper as
begin
  if regexp_like(ora_sysevent,'create|alter|drop|truncate|rename','i') then
   Raise_Application_Error(-20999, 'Attempt To ALTER A cannot perform DDL operation');
  end if;     
end;
```

by use of [`ora_sysevent`](http://psoug.org/reference/system_events.html) pseudocolumn.